# Warning issued upon moving site files to PHP7 server

Tags: wordpress, php-7

My site has a checkout which gives the following warnings together on a white page after submitting a test purchase.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in wordpress.php on line 1460
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wordpress.php on line 1842

Line 1460 refers to the following: `$totals->quantity = $total_qty;`

This is a part of the code:

```
if (!function_exists('yak_get_totals')) {
    /**
     * Return an array containing the total quantity and total price of an array of items.
     */
    function yak_get_totals(&$items) {
        $total_qty = 0;
        $total_price = 0;
        foreach ($items as $key=>$item) {
            if (!isset($item->price)) {
                $item->price = yak_calc_price($item->id, $item->cat_id, $item->price);
            }
            $total_qty += $item->quantity;
            $total_price += ($item->price * $item->quantity);
        }
        $totals->quantity = $total_qty;
        $totals->price = $total_price;
        return $totals;
    }
}
```

This code is a part of a plugin I have been using on WordPress for a number of years. The developer of the plugin discontinued it so now with a change of servers I am trying to update the code to work in PHP7.

On the back-end the plugin is working as it should. It sends out an email indicating the sale was made and the purchase shows up in the order area etc. However, a customer doesn't get to the order confirmation page they instead get this page.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this issue. The line 1460 which `$totals->quantity = $total_qty;`

$totals needs to be declared as follows: `$totals = new StdClass;`

Once this was done both errors never occurred again.

Hope this might help others in the future!

Thanks!